# Difference between O_CLOEXEC and TIOCEXCL

Tags: c, linux

I use a device on serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (uses FTDI) and I don't want to leak any file descriptors to other spawned processes so I set the close-on-exec flag on the descriptor. Could you tell me what is the difference between setting O_CLOEXEC while opening:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int fd, rc;
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("error open:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    rc = close(fd);     
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        perror("error close:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And setting close-on-exec with ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int fd, rc;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("error open:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    rc = ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL);
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        perror("error ioctl:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    rc = close(fd);     
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        perror("error close:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TIOCEXCL` is not "close on exec". It puts a terminal in "exclusive" mode. It has nothing to do with preventing leaking file descriptors. You may be thinking of `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, old_flags | FD_CLOEXEC)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TIOCEXCL` does *not* set the close-on-exec flag (that would be `FIOCLEX`, or, equivalently, `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)`).

To answer the question you thought you were asking:

Specifying `O_CLOEXEC` when you `open()` a file will set the close-on-exec flag before it returns, saving you another call and, importantly, ensuring that there is no race condition where another thread might call `exec()` after `open()` but before the subsequent `fcntl()`.

If you really need to set or unset the flag at any other time (I've never needed to), you can do so with `fcntl F_SETFD`, passing `FD_CLOEXEC` or `0` respectively.

Comment: `open(..., O_CLOEXEC)` doesn't just save a call, it ensures the flag is set atomically. Otherwise, if you have a multithreaded program, one thread might call `exec()` right between an `open()` and subsequent `fcntl(..., FD_CLOEXEC)` call.

Comment: Thanks @G.Sliepen - I thought that was the case, but wanted to check it was within the syscall and not something implemented in the C library.  I'll add that information into my answer.